# Backbone.js + underscore.js + jQuery in requireJS... is this the right way?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm trying to learning more about requireJS. So, if i understand it correctly, thw following code should be legit. Is this the right way to make my application modular?

This is `application.js`, where `data-main` attribute points:

```js
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/vendor', // By default, load all from vendor folder
    shim: {
        'backbone' : { // Do not support module loading
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'], // Do not support module loading
            exports: 'Backbone' 
        },
    },
    paths: {
        models: '../application/models', // Load from this folder if starts with user
        views: '../application/views',   // As above...
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'backbone', 'views/user'], function($, Backbone, UserView) {
});
```

And my module for a view/model (pretty useless right now):

File `application/views/user.js`:

```js
// underscore should be loaded now
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'models/user'], function($, Backbone, User) { 
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        model: User,

        el: $('tr'),    

        initialize: function() {}
    });
});
```

File `application/models/user.js`:

```js
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) { // underscore should be loaded now
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
    });
});
```

Comment: what does define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'models/user'], function($, Backbone, User) { means? is this a convention for certain frame work in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to shim underscore as well since it's not AMD compatible.

```
 underscore: {
  exports: '_'
}
```

I'd recommend looking into https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/ as it takes a lot of the headache out of using RequireJS.

Comment: jQuery is already AMD-compatible.  Shim is for library's that don't support AMD.

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash instead underscore, is a superior full compatible solution and support AMD load. Check benchmarks and documentation ;)

```
requirejs.config({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: { 
        'jquery': ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min','libs/jquery-min'],
        'lodash': 'libs/lodash.min',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {deps:['lodash','jquery'], exports: 'Backbone'}
    }
});

require([
    'jquery', 'lodash','backbone'
],
function($, _){
    return {};
});
```